# How to always show tableView cell when i scroll

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I need to always show cell with segmentControll, how can i do it?

[image: a busy cat]

[image: a busy cat]

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. Here is what I would do.

## 1

Don't put the segmented control as part of the table. Simply move it outside the UITableView. With that being said, if you are using a TableView Controller, you have to switch to a ViewController and add TableView to it.

## 2

This is a way to create a header for your table. Maybe that's what you want.

Use this method if you want a title:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Or this one if you want a custom view:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

And for the height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```